# PHP Find Substring inside String Array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have the following array:

```
$historicalFullList = ['Fecha','H-kWH-Total','H-kWH-Pico','H-kWH-Resto','H-kWH-Valle','H-Acum-Pico','H-Acum-Resto','H-Acum-Valle','H-Fecha-Pico','H-Fecha-Resto','H-Fecha-Valle','H-kW-Pico','H-kW-Resto','H-kW-Valle','H-kVARH-Total','error','factMult','H-kW-Pico-C','H-kW-Resto-C','H-kW-Valle-C'];
```

I want to create a function to find if the substring 'H-k' exists in the array. (in this example array it should return TRUE)

For some reason the following code doesn't work. Is there a better way to do this?

```
function test($substring, $array){

    foreach ($array as $item){
        if (strpos($substring, $item)!== false){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

then called it..

```
if (test('H-k',$historicalFullList)){
    do stuff...
}
```

Comment: try to change your comparison operator `!==` to `!=`

Comment: Doesn't work how?

Comment: show how did you call `test(...)` function

Comment: @u_mulder it allways returns false

Comment: Because first element of your array has no `H-k`. And `return` stops function execution.

Comment: @coderodour No. You want the `!==`. strpos can return both `false` and `0` with opposite meanings (`false` means not found, `0` means found at first character). If you made the comparison `!=`, if the string started with the substring, it would be found and return `0`, which is a falsy value (can be coerced to false) so the type strict comparison is needed.

Comment: AAAHHH..ofcourse, that. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

move your return false out of the foreach, else it will return false after the first comparison if it doesn't contain `$substr`.

```
function test($substring, $array){
    foreach ($array as $item){
        if (strpos($item,$substring)!== false){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;       
}
```

Also, swap the needle and the haystack for strpos.

Comment: i see your point.... but it still returns false every run... maybe there is a problem checking or substrings with "-" and that type of character?

Comment: We both got the haystack and the needle mixed up. Swap the $item and $substring in strpos

Comment: see http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c96fbdfaa44b56db807eda55b2f36a3fabfcdf62